# how to make a full backup of ubuntu server for another computer?

Tags: server, 15.10, backup

I have a Ubuntu 15.10 server, which currently has a bunch of software installed on. Now, I want to make a full backup of everything there (including profiles, configs, etc...) on this computer (virtually on Parallels Desktop) for another physical computer which I've recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 server on it.

So how can I transfer this system completely into that computer?
I tried PinguyBuilder and Systemback, but they were not what I wanted.

Considering that if there is a way, which would need not or at least a Internet connection (specially on physical computer) would be awesome.

Any help?

P.S:
I know there are many topics for backup things, but they are not exactly for a non-gui server, or maybe I couldn't find what is suitable for me.

Comment: Maybe disk cloning software like Clonezilla may do what you want ? It can backup the entire disk contents into an image, which you can then restore onto the other machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clonezilla is a reliable tool which does exactly what you want to do.
Download [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable) and create a bootable DVD or USB media.

Boot from the media and clone the content of the system installation.
I created presentations which explain how you have to do everything :

[Create a backup using Clonezilla](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13-GCZyxH51pWD-aMzmD-QNpDr7U28ZqTmEB-Iy3wizM/edit#slide=id.p) | 
[Restore a backup using Clonezilla](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1mSc1BAJBIQMbKKzI2OjG9tWEt7p7GeGY50InYgWzgVQ/edit#slide=id.p)

Comment: Does this recognize partitions on virtual machine?

Comment: @Snowleaf : When you have your system installed in a virtual machine and boot from the Clonezilla ISO file or DVD / USB media which you have inserted in this virtual machine, then it recognizes the partitions of the virtual disk. :)